# Combine list data in R using Merge?

Tags: r, list, merge

I would like to combine two lists:

```
data1 data2
a 1     a 1
b 2     b 2
c 3     c 3
d 4     f 6
e 5     g 7
```

so that the final product is:

```
data3
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
e 5
f 6
g 7
```

I have tried using variations of merge, but inevitably end up loosing something from each list.

Thank you for your help! 
Thank you!

Comment: What's the actual structure of your lists?  Please use `dput` so that we can re-create your problem.  Also, you have a conceptual gap here--what do you do if data1 contains `h 8` but data2 contains `h 9`?

Answer (score 6):

use the argument `all=TRUE` of `merge`:

```
merge(data1,data2,all=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

One option to consider is

`unique(rbind(data1, data2 ) )`